# SumIf returns value of 0 when using worksheet.function SumIf

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a sumif function using excel's worksheetfunction, please see below

```
Public Function sumif(Range As Variant, criteria As Variant, sum_range As Variant)
On Error Resume Next
sumif = WorksheetFunction.sumif(Range, criteria, sum_range)
If IsError(sumif) Then
sumif = ""
End If
End Function
```

With this public function I am attempting to sum the number of hours certain locations are logged onto a specific system. I have included what I am trying to do below

```
Private Sub lookupWLDetails()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim vntSiteID As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim rngDS As Range

With Sheet3
lngLastRow = lastRowInCol(.Columns("B"), 11)
Set rngDS = .Range(.Cells(11, "B"), _
.Cells(lngLastRow, "X"))
End With
```

there is nothing wrong with lastrowinCol function this has been successfully used several times in same excel document so no need to paste that

```
With Sheet9
lngLastRow = lastRowInCol(.Columns("B"), 2)
For lngRow = 2 To lngLastRow
vntSiteID = .Cells(lngRow, "B")
.Cells(lngRow, "C") = sumif(rngDS.Columns(3), vntSiteID, rngDS.Columns(7)) 
.Cells(lngRow, "D") = sumif(rngDS.Columns(3), vntSiteID, rngDS.Columns(8)) 
Next lngRow
End With
End Sub
```

- The top piece of Code is separate from the bottom 2 pieces of code
- The bottom 2 pieces of code are part of the same sub

The purpose of this bit of code is to loop through col B on sheet 9 (this holds a list of each site on the report) and then sum all values in each requested column within sheet 3 so long as the site held on sheet 3 col D matches siteID from sheet 9

I am not receiving any errors I just get the value 0 returned from all my sumif attempts

Any help anyone can provide would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the answer to my own question in the end but thought I'd share it on her in case anyone wishes to use and adapt this code or is having the same issue I was having.

the only issue with the SumIf function was the declaration of the first range

```
.Cells(lngRow, "C") = sumif(rngDS.Columns(3), vntSiteID, rngDS.Columns(7)) 
.Cells(lngRow, "D") = sumif(rngDS.Columns(3), vntSiteID, rngDS.Columns(8))
```

These should show

```
.Cells(lngRow, "C") = sumif(rngDS, vntSiteID, rngDS.Columns(7)) 
.Cells(lngRow, "D") = sumif(rngDS, vntSiteID, rngDS.Columns(8))
```